# Space replaced by 'u' character Xcode 7 beta 5

Tags: xcode

[image]

In my Xcode editor view all the space characters appear to have been replaced by an unrecognizable character (like a `u` but with square corners). I am using Xcode 7 beta 5. How can I fix this ?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've inadvertently turned on `Show Invisibles`. Go to the `Editor` menu and select `Hide Invisibles` to turn this feature off.